# Deploying configuration to Kubernetes pods on GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I've been looking into using Kubernetes on Google Compute Engine. I have pods with configuration that needs to be deployed to them. Currently, I'm using a persistent disk to do this. However, as a persistent disk cannot be mounted more than once it cannot be used to deploy configuration if I use more than 1 pod.

What is the best way to do this? ConfigMaps won't work as I need to deploy a directory structure as configuration. The only solution I can see is rebuilding my docker container every time I need to change my config. Is that really the best way?

Comment: Have you had the chance to look at Google Container Engine? Dynamic configuration for applications via ConfigMap API is supported since the 1.2.0 version release. More information is available here: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/

Comment: ConfigMaps don't support any sort of directory structure, which I unfortunately need for my configuration.

Comment: Probably Redis with Flocker can help you accomplish what you are looking for?

Comment: Is your configuration read-only? "A feature of [GCE persistent disks] is that they can be mounted as read-only by multiple consumers simultaneously." http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes supports [several types of volumes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/) that are appropriate for different applications. As jwadsack suggested in his comment you can use a `gcePersistentDisk` volume which can be mounted as read-only by multiple consumers simultaneously. NFS (`nfs` volume) can also be mounted and used by multiple writers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigMaps` allow mapping from files and directories. The main doc provides info. You likely need only very little adaptation to what you are used to from static files. Also ConfigMaps are definitely the only way to go, since binding volumes for everything but data defeats the purposes of Kubernetes a little, imo.